# Improper NULL Termination c/c++

Tags: c++

I am recently trying a static code analyzer on existing c++ source (mixed with C ). I found many error occurs when i tried something like this

```
char* buff= new char[length];
size_t readbytes = fread(buff,length,1, file)
```

I get improper null pointer termination on buff. I tried something like this -

```
if((readbytes=fread(buff,length,1,file))<length){ /*dont do anything*/}
else {/*rest of the code*/}
```

which does not worked.
Also tried to check with `strlen(buff) == length` - also did not work.

Similar high risk issues I got with memcpy, memmove  when my dest is of type `char[constant size]`

what I am missing here to make it write so that no null termination risk can be avoided?

Comment: Please quote the messages verbatim, in full and as text.

Comment: `char* buff= new ichar[length];` -- I guess you were not aware that you need to make room for the terminating NULL?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't want to use string and file streams?

Comment: not allowed to change headers - as it may affect other apps using the library :-(

Comment: @DebS then you should include that info as well as which headers are available.

Answer (score 0):

> what I am missing here to make it write so that no null termination risk can be avoided?

Your understanding of how `fread` works is not correct.

`fread()` does not null terminate the input buffer. Not only that, the buffer may contain any number of (can be zero, can be non-zero) null characters if the file being read from contains binary data.

If you are sure that the file contains only textual content, you can do the following:

1. Make sure that you read one less than the number of characters the buffer can hold.
2. Terminate the buffer with the null character.
3. Also, you need to swap the two middle arguments. See [`fread` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) for the meanings of the two middle arguments.

```
size_t readbytes = fread(buff, 1, length - 1, file);
buff[readbytes] = '\0';
```

---

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread:

> **buffer**    -   pointer to the array where the read objects are stored
>   **size**    -   size of each object in bytes
>   **count**   -   the number of the objects to be read
>   **stream**  -   the stream to read

Let's say the input file has one line and the contents are:

```
abcdef
```

And a buffer is defined as:

```
char buff[20];
```

If you use

```
size_t n = fread(buff, 20, 1, file);
```

then, `n` will be 0. You are requesting to read 1 object of size 20 and there are only 7 characters in the file (I am including a newline character too).

If you use

```
size_t n = fread(buff, 1, 20, file);
```

then, `n` wil be 7. You are requesting to read 20 objects of size 1 but the function was able to read only 7 objects of size 1.

Now, you can decide whether

```
size_t readbytes = fread(buff, length - 1, 1, file);
```

or

```
size_t readbytes = fread(buff, 1, length - 1, file);
```

is appropriate for your use case.

Comment: fread(buff, length, 1 file) is correct - size of buff is length and count is 1

Comment: @DebS, not true. Please see the documentation.

Comment: @R Sahu in this code the size of each object is length and count is 1 so - size of buffer is count (count*1)

Comment: @RSahu by size of object, you mean size_of(char)? maybe it would be more readable if you used that instead of magic number `1`? Also a new line character may actually be two characters in certain operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong to assume that `fread` is supposed to add a terminating null on the first place. Or that terminating null is not present in the middle of the buffer. You should allocate +1 byte and add terminating null manually to ensure that it is present somewhere in the buffer:

```
char * buff{new ichar[length + 1]};
size_t readbytes{fread(buff, length, 1, file)};
if(readbytes <= length)
{
    buff = readbytes[readbytes] = '\0';
}
else
{
    abort(); // fread return value is unexpected
}
assert(strlen(buff) <= readbytes);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use string and file streams to avoid the issue entirely. When you use C++ you might as well use all those nice stream functions it offers to avoid this kind of issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

const char* filePath = "yourFile.txt";

int main() {
    std::string line = "";
    std::ifstream inFile (filePath, std::ifstream::in);
    if (inFile.good()) {
        std::getline(inFile, line, '\n');
    }
    inFile.close();
    // more checks here (inFile.fail() || inFile.bad()) + cleanup
    /* Do what you want with line */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is there something wrong with my answer? if so feel free to leave a https://idownvotedbecau.se link so I can improve.